# Iterate through files and read records

Tags: c#, file, fixed-length-record

What is the fastest way to the following in C# 3.5 :

1. Iterate through files in a directory
2. Read the file's records (fixed length of 247 characters)
3. Convert the fixed length string of each record to a Struct or Class.

Thanks

Comment: fastest in terms of performance or development time?

Comment: I think you've just outlined the algorithm: iterate over all files in a directory, read one line at a time, have a class whose constructor accepts a string and extracts the appropriate data. Since you want to read all data, any other approach will just add overhead.

Comment: fastest in terms of performance, as I have a requirement to read thousands of records per minute

Comment: Is each file 247 characters long or has each file several strings of 247 characters? Is there a special sign between each record (eg. newline etc.)? How should these 247 characters be interpreted? Etc., etc...

Comment: each file has several strings of 247 characters. I then have a document specifying each column width. There is no newline (or any other symbol) between each record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be relatively fast to write:

```
var myStructs = 
from file in Directory.GetFiles(".", "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
select ConvertFileToStructs(File.ReadAllText(file));
```

If this is the fastest way possible, performance-wise? Probably not, but it won't make a huge difference. What will impact the performance is the implementation of the deserialization within the ConvertFileToStructs() function. But to answer this, we need to know the specific format of your files.

---

Just read your comments. I would suggest the following parsing:

```
List<MyStruct> ConvertFileToStructs(string content, int[] mapping)
{
    var records = new List<MyStruct>();
    int length = content.Length();
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i += 247)
         records.Add(ConvertRecordToStruct(content.Substring(i,247), mapping));
    return records;
}

MyStruct ConvertRecordToStruct(string record, int[] mapping)
{
    MyStruct s;
    s.Field1 =  record.Substring(mapping[0], mapping[1]);
    //set other fields
    return s;
}
```

This code could probably be optimized for performance, but I don't think it would change things dramatically, especially because I/O to disk is involved and Substring() is pretty fast (see http://dotnetperls.com/substring). Of course you will have to test this on your machine.

Comment: What exactly would you need to know about the format of the files?
They are text files with a fixed length of 247 for each record.

Comment: From your question I understood that you want to convert the record into a struct or class, which implies that they represent a serialized object. My question is if the serializiation format is XML, CSV or something else. Because it matters if you parse with an XML parser, simple string.Split and Join or regular expressions. Maybe you intend that the string should not be parsed further, but then why require conversion?

Comment: my initial plan is to read each record, convert the fixed length string to a struct or class.. do some processing..  then insert into a DB with linq.
but how would I convert the fixed length record to a Struct?

Answer (score 0):

custom class to handle files

```
   class customFile
        {
            string fileText;
            public string FileText
            {
                get { return fileText; }
                set { fileText = value; }
            }
        }
```

read all text

```
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath);
        List<customFile> customFiles = new List<customFile>();
        foreach (string file in filePaths)
        {
            customFiles.Add(new customFile { FileText = File.ReadAllText(file) });
        }
```